# How to save command cooldown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The code below adds a cooldown for command, but when bot restarts, the cooldown resets. So how can I make the bot remember from previous usage? If the cooldown limit is 5 times per day and if the member used 3 times and if bot restarts it should start from where it was left for all members.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

from utils import Bot
from utils import CommandWithCooldown

class Members():
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.command(pass_context=True, cls=CommandWithCooldown)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 600, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
        await self.bot.say(msg)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Members(bot))
```

Comment: You'd have to save the state of `ping._buckets`, and then load that state back into `ping._buckets` in your `on_ready` event.  I'd try `pickle`ing the object first, and if that doesn't work you'll have to dig into [the code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/async/discord/ext/commands) to understand how it's put together.  It looks like all the relevant code is split between `core.py` and `cooldowns.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to what Patrick Haugh suggested, the cooldown mapping is stored in `Command._buckets`. You can pickle the bucket before the bot starts and save it after the bot finishes. For your convenience, replace the Bot class with the following (a.k.a "moneypatching"):

```
token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
prefix = "?"
cooldown_info_path = "cd.pkl"

from discord.ext import commands


class Bot(commands.Bot):

    async def start(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import os, pickle
        if os.path.exists(cooldown_info_path):  # on the initial run where "cd.pkl" file hadn't been created yet
            with open(cooldown_info_path, 'rb') as f:
                d = pickle.load(f)
                for name, func in self.commands.items():
                    if name in d:  # if the Command name has a CooldownMapping stored in file, override _bucket
                        self.commands[name]._buckets = d[name]
        return await super().start(*args, **kwargs)

    async def logout(self):
        import pickle
        with open(cooldown_info_path, 'wb') as f:
            # dumps a dict of command name to CooldownMapping mapping
            pickle.dump({name: func._buckets for name, func in self.commands.items()}, f)
        return await super().logout()


bot = Bot(prefix)
# everything else as usual

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def hello(ctx):
    msg = "Hello... {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)


class ACog:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 600, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
        await self.bot.say(msg)


bot.add_cog(ACog(bot))
bot.run(token)
```

---

This will save the cooldown data to "cd.pkl" when the bot is properly logged out.

Comment: If i use multiple cog files do i need to add this in all files or shall i use `import`  by adding this code in seperate file.

Comment: @Demotry you can use imports. I suggest maybe saving that class in an `objects.py` (seems to be the convention for discord.py bots) and then `from objects import Bot` or it’s a project `from .objects import Bot`, from which ever file that needed to use it.

Comment: In theory it will work. You should post your codes so I can see where the problem lies in the code.

Comment: What exactly did you mean by not working? If you meant the `AttributeError` it’s because you forgot `self` as a parameter to `ping`. `async def ping(self, ctx):`

Comment: not working means if i restart bot  cooldown not saves for commands in cog files.

Comment: but cooldown saves for those commands which is in main bot.py file  .

Comment: Yup I see where the problem is, it might be that cogs or extension commands aren’t stored in `self.commands`, this could be a bit more complicated, when I have access to a pc I’ll look into it.

Comment: @Demotry it turned out that `.close()` removed cog commands so they were never saved by my code. I rewrote the Bot class, it should work fine now.

Comment: So only i need to replace new code in `utils.py` file  and were to add `cooldown_info_path = "cd.pkl"` this one in main.py or all file.

Comment: In utils where the Bot class is defined