# How do I save command cooldowns using discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I know there's a question on here about this, but the rewrite seems to change `client.commands.items()`. That command doesn't exist anymore, and seems to be replaced by `client.commands` which returns a set containing all of the bot's commands. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128774/6076716) answer has the old way of doing it, but I don't know how to properly get the data out of the set. Sets only return `pop`'d items, and I can't seem to easily determine which things are being `pop`'d and how to then re-add them back to the commands list with the proper cooldown times. I'm either going about this wrong, or there's another way to handle this sort of thing.

I guess my question is, how do I easily get the information from the set returned by `client.commands`, and only configure the cooldowns for each command in that set?

Comment: It looks like `client.all_commands` is a dict, so you can try to use that as a drop-in replacement.  As an aside, you can try iterating through `client.commands` and modify the elements in-place without modifying the set at all.

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60*60*24, commands.BucketType.user)
async def daily(ctx):
    YOUR_CODE
```

Cooldown:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, time(in seconds), commands.BucketType.user)
```

Comment: Hello! I was wondering if you could explain where you found the `_save()` thing. I couldn't find it anywhere in the discord.py source code, or the documentation. I just have a few questions about how it works, and where it saves the cooldown data to. Thanks!

Comment: Hello! The _save() is a locally defined command and is not in any way related to the cooldown. I have edited the code a bit to make it clear. The cooldown is not saved anywhere in any file, just adding the cooldown line to your code with help you. Thanks!