# discord.py storing command cooldowns

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to set cooldown for my commands but when I restart the bot the cooldowns are lost.
I'm trying to find a way to store the cooldowns and reuse them but i could not achieve it by looking at docs

```py
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
cooldown_info_path = "cd.pkl"
class Bot(commands.Bot):

    async def start(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import os, pickle
        if os.path.exists(cooldown_info_path):  # on the initial run where "cd.pkl" file hadn't been created yet
            with open(cooldown_info_path, 'rb') as f:
                d = pickle.load(f)
                for name, func in self.commands.items():
                    if name in d:  # if the Command name has a CooldownMapping stored in file, override _bucket
                        self.commands[name]._buckets = d[name]
        return await super().start(*args, **kwargs)

    async def logout(self):
        import pickle
        with open(cooldown_info_path, 'wb') as f:
            # dumps a dict of command name to CooldownMapping mapping
            pickle.dump({name: func._buckets for name, func in self.commands.items()}, f)
        return await super().logout()

client = Bot(command_prefix=">")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")


@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("HEY")

class ACog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.bot = client

    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 600, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx)
        await ctx.send(msg)


client.add_cog(ACog(client))
client.run(token)
```

found this code on Stack but it does not work...
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could to this by getting the cooldown for each command when the bot disconnects and save the information in just a `txt` or `json` file. However it would be kinda messy since you would have to keep track of cooldowns **per user**.

Comment: But in general, why do you want this functionality? Unless you are restarting the bot a lot for testing purposes.

Comment: the bot is functional but when i update the bot and restart it I loose the user cooldowns

Comment: I understand that. So I assume that you are updating and restarting the bot a lot because you are testing things. Instead of trying to hack a way to get user cooldowns, I would use cogs. I know you already have a cog in there but it doesn't seem to be fully utilized. You can reload a cog without having to restart the entire bot, so you can update a function, reload that cog, and then test it. If you find yourself testing often, it may be worth to having a cog purely for testing purposes.

Comment: but still, i want to know how can I save cooldowns for users as i don't want to only update commands in cog but also main file even if i restart the bot after 10 days i still want users to keep their CD like there is a weekly commands and i don't want people to use it :(

Comment: Ah ok fair enough. I haven't done this but it seems like your on the right track with the pickling. So I assume you used the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117681/how-to-save-command-cooldown) post. I would try making another command purely to see the cooldowns before and after restarting, maybe just with print statements. I would also refer back to the comments of that post^. It seems they had trouble getting it to work across both the main and cog files but figured it out.

Comment: that code does not work I read through the comments and it does not work
the code that I have posted is from my test bot and it contains only that many commands @Roopesh-J

Answer (score 0):

I have made a system like this before.
What I do is store a big dictionary in a JSON-file.
The keys being the user-id, and the value being a timestamp of when they last used the command.

The code for the command itself is here:

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    last_used_time = get_last_used(ctx.author.id)
    available_time = last_used_time + timedelta(hours=1)
    if not available_time < datetime.utcnow():
        return

    await ctx.send("HEY")

    set_last_used(ctx.author.id)
```

Note the `timedelta(hours=1)` is the timedelta of the cooldown.

`get_last_used` and `set_last_used` are defined as:

```
def get_last_used(user_id: int):
    with open('data/TimelyCooldowns.json') as cooldowns_file:
        cooldowns = json.loads(cooldowns_file.read())

    time_string = cooldowns.get(str(user_id))
    if time_string is not None:
        return datetime.strptime(time_string, fmt)
    else:
        return datetime.min
```

```
def set_last_used(user_id: int):
    with open('data/TimelyCooldowns.json') as cooldowns_file:
        cooldowns = json.loads(cooldowns_file.read())

    cooldowns[str(user_id)] = datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow(), fmt)
    with open('data/TimelyCooldowns.json', 'w') as cooldowns_file:
        cooldowns_file.write(json.dumps(cooldowns, indent=4))
```